# Can you make VB Script ONLY match on specific objects and not generalized objects?

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I'm writing a test for a website. You have to log in twice on different pages in order to access the second page.

Here is an example of what I have written (this works sometimes):

```
If Browser("EXAMPLE").Page("LogInPage").WebEdit("ID").Exist Then
    Browser("EXAMPLE").Page("LogInPage").WebEdit("ID").Set "tporte51"
    Browser("EXAMPLE").Page("LogInPage").WebEdit("PASSWORD").SetSecure "HiddenPassword"
    Browser("EXAMPLE").Page("LogInPage").WebButton("I Concur").Click
End If

If Browser("EXAMPLE").Page("LogInPage2").WebEdit("txtUserName").Exist Then
    Browser("EXAMPLE").Page("LogInPage2").WebEdit("txtUserName").Set "testuser"
    Browser("EXAMPLE").Page("LogInPage2").WebEdit("txtPASSWORD").SetSecure "HiddenPassword2"
    Browser("EXAMPLE").Page("LogInPage2").Link("Login").Click
End If
```

My issue is that when running this in UFT, sometimes it recognizes the second login (WebEdit("txtUserName")) as the first login (WebEdit("ID")) and tries to use the wrong credentials.

Any ideas for remedies?

Comment: What is the hierarchy of objects? Is it really `Browser->Page->WebEdit->WebEdit`? Also in 2nd `If` condition you are checking `Browser->Page->WebEdit->WebEdit` existence, but filling the data in `Browser->Page->WebEdit`. If you are identifying your both Browsers and Pages uniquely than it should work properly with proper hierarchy.

Comment: I fixed the code example to eliminate the errors I made while copying from a virtual machine and hiding any identifiable information.

Comment: Can you identify all your object uniquely? If not, could you post relevant HTML source code from both the pages?

Comment: 1. Turn off smart identification 2. Change Exist to Exist(seconds)

Comment: I'm not sure about how to identify them uniquely. The source code is 2 corporate websites that I shouldn't post online. Sorry!

Comment: Try to make sure you can identify your both login screen uniquely. If you can do that then your problem is solved.

Comment: You said that you have to go to two different URL's, and the these logins are on different screens, So what you can do is, add the URL property to the Page object and that will make sure that the page is identified uniquely, you will also have to make sure that smart identification is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it appears that you're using the same `Browser` object with different `Page`s in order to differentiate between different browser tabs(?).

Please note that `Browser` is used to identify a tab and each `Browser` has only one `Page` at a time. The `Page` object is only meant to organise the object repository and has no role in identifying objects. For more information see this [blog post](https://community.hpe.com/t5/All-About-the-Apps/Understanding-the-web-test-object-model-in-HP-Unified-Functional/ba-p/6168133#.V-p9afB942w).